# How to get 2 loops to increment at the same time?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get 2 For loops to increment at the same time but am only able to get it to where one loop increments and after that loop has gone through its complete loop then the 2nd loop increments. I would like for the code to go down the list of both loops at the same time where it goes:

set criteria1 (1) and criteria2 (1) to the rngstart and rngend 
 then runs the For i = (rngStart.Row + 2) To (rngEnd.Row - 3) section and outputs to a text file

then set criteria1 (2) and criteria2 (2) to the rngstart and rngend
 then runs the For i = (rngStart.Row + 2) To (rngEnd.Row - 3) section and outputs to a text file

etc.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong and how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am trying to resolve the issue with:

```
Sub ExportStuffToText()


Dim rngFind As Range, rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range, rngPrint As Range, cell As Range
Dim Criteria1, Criteria2
Dim sTextPath
Dim strCriteria1() As String
Dim strCriteria2() As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim intCriteria1Max As Integer
Dim intCriteria2Max As Integer
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim str_text As String
Dim sLine As String
Dim sType As String

Set rngFind = Columns("B")

intCriteria1Max = 5
ReDim strCriteria1(1 To intCriteria1Max)

strCriteria1(1) = "Entry1"
strCriteria1(2) = "Entry2"
strCriteria1(3) = "Entry3"
strCriteria1(4) = "Entry4"
strCriteria1(5) = "Entry5"

intCriteria2Max = 5
ReDim strCriteria2(1 To intCriteria2Max)

strCriteria2(1) = "Entry2"
strCriteria2(2) = "Entry3"
strCriteria2(3) = "Entry4"
strCriteria2(4) = "Entry5"
strCriteria2(5) = "Entry6"

 For a = 1 To intCriteria1Max
 For b = 1 To intCriteria2Max

            Criteria1 = strCriteria1(a)
            Set rngStart = rngFind.Find(What:=Criteria1, LookIn:=xlValues)
            sTextPath = rngStart
            Criteria2 = strCriteria2(b)
            Set rngEnd = rngFind.Find(What:=Criteria2, LookIn:=xlValues)


    If rngStart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Criteria1 not found"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf rngEnd Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Criteria2 not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

FileNum = FreeFile
str_text = ""

For i = (rngStart.Row + 2) To (rngEnd.Row - 3)
    sLine = ""
    sType = Sheets![Sheetnamegoeshere].Cells(i, 8).Text
    If sType = "somestring" Or sType = "adifferentstring" Then
    For j = 1 To 2
        If j > 1 Then
            sLine = sLine & vbTab
        End If

    sLine = sLine & Sheets![Sheetnamegoeshere].Cells(i, j).Text
        Next j
        If Not Len(Trim(Replace(sLine, vbTab, ""))) = 0 Then
            If i > 4 Then
                str_text = str_text & IIf(str_text = "", "", vbNewLine) & sLine
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next

Open sTextPath For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, str_text
    Close #FileNum
    str_text = ""

 Next b
 Next a


End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the same counter for the two with a global variable?

Comment: I am nor sure what loop is the one that you want to increment at the same time; you have about four  in the procedure. Also the whole thing looks a little busy. I think that you are trying to get values between two ranges and then write to a file correct?

Comment: @ako I have tried that but unfortunately I could not get it to work in the manner that I wanted.

Comment: @Alfredo You are correct that I am trying to get values between a range.  Criteria1 is the starting point and criteria2 is the stopping point. I am trying to get the for a and the for b sections to increment at the same time.  I originally wanted to use a single list where it worked like:

 strCriteria(1) = "Entry1"
 strCriteria(2) = "Entry2"
 strCriteria(3) = "Entry3"

 and criteria 1 would be entry1 and criteria2 would be entry2 then run the For i = (rngStart.Row + 2) To (rngEnd.Row - 3) section and then increment to where criteria1 would be entry2 and criteria2 would be entry3.

Comment: ok I am trying to see if I can do something to correct the code. One more thing there is a variable "Sheetnamegoeshere" what is that is that the same sheet we will be searching or a different one ?

Comment: @Alfredo Yes "Sheetnamegoeshere" is the name of the excel sheet that the script will be executed against due to the workbook having numerous sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made some modifications in the code. I should be working but I did not test it. Give it a try.

Note that I split the original procedure into three smaller ones. Usually if you have a huge amount of variables on the top, it's a sign that the procedure is too large.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportStuffToText()

    Dim shToWork As Worksheet
    Dim arrCriteria(4, 1) As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range

    ' Add the criterias pairs
    arrCriteria(0, 0) = "Entry1"
    arrCriteria(0, 1) = "Entry2"

    arrCriteria(1, 0) = "Entry2"
    arrCriteria(1, 1) = "Entry3"

    arrCriteria(2, 0) = "Entry3"
    arrCriteria(2, 1) = "Entry4"

    arrCriteria(3, 0) = "Entry4"
    arrCriteria(3, 1) = "Entry5"

    arrCriteria(3, 0) = "Entry5"
    arrCriteria(3, 1) = "Entry6"


    ' Put the name of the sheet here "Sheetnamegoeshere"
    Set shToWork = Sheets("Sheetnamegoeshere")
    Set rngFind = shToWork.Columns("B")

    Dim t As Long

    ' Loop through my criteria pairs.
    For t = LBound(arrCriteria, 1) To UBound(arrCriteria, 1)

        'Try to find the values pair.
        Set rngStart = rngFind.Find(what:=arrCriteria(t, 0), LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set rngEnd = rngFind.Find(what:=arrCriteria(t, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not rngStart Is Nothing And Not rngEnd Is Nothing Then

            ' Create the text to append.
            strText = GetStringToAppend(rngStart, rngEnd)

            'Write to the file
           WriteToFile rngStart.Value, strText

        Else

            ' If one or more of the ranges is nothing then
            ' show a message.
            If rngStart Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Criteria1 not found"
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf rngEnd Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Criteria2 not found"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next t

End Sub

'Creates a string that will be append to the file.
Function GetStringToAppend(ByRef rStart As Range, _
                           ByRef rEnd As Range) As String

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim sType As String
    Dim ret As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'Grab the sheet from one of the ranges.
    Set sh = rStart.Parent

    For i = (rStart.Row + 2) To (rEnd.Row - 3)

        sType = sh.Cells(i, 8).Text

        If sType = "somestring" Or sType = "adifferentstring" Then
            For j = 1 To 2
                If j > 1 Then
                    sLine = sLine & vbTab
                End If

                sLine = sLine & sh.Cells(i, j).Text
            Next j

            If Not Len(Trim$(Replace(sLine, vbTab, vbNullString))) = 0 Then
                If i > 4 Then
                    ret = ret & IIf(ret = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNewLine) & sLine
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Return the value
    GetStringToAppend = ret

End Function


'Procedure to write to the file.
Sub WriteToFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, _
                ByVal strContent As String)

    Dim FileNum As Integer

    FileNum = FreeFile

    Open strFilePath For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, strContent
    Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This definitely gives me something to review and learn what you were doing and why.  Thank you very much for that.  I did try the code and it comes up with a Path/File access error and the output for the For I = section is off for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help this is working beautifully.  I resolved the output issues and just have to resolve the Path/File access error that is occurring and all will be golden.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. I am not sure whats wrong with the file though.